# Dump input device file using getevent tool on Android

Tags: android, unix, adb

I have a rooted Android 7 phone and I would like to dump unix input event files. Using adb I could do it using the following command:

```
adb shell getevent -t /dev/input/event7 > recorded_touch_events.txt
```

This will dump the event7 file into recorded_touch_events.txt. But this only works when the phone is connected by usb cable with the PC. Using Android I can dump files with the following code:

```
th = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        private Process exec;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","getevent -t /dev/input/event7"});
                InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(
                        exec.getInputStream());
                String s;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
                while(((s = br.readLine()) != null) && run){
                    // write line to text file
                }
                is.close();
                exec.destroy();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
}
```

In this way, I could store every read line in a text file.

Are there other approaches (probably faster ones) for directly dumping the event file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getevent` is used to print input events out in human readable form. For example during interactive debug session. You do not need to use `getevent` for *just dumping* or any other computer processing task. Just open and read the input file. The event record format is [very simple](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt).

Comment: Is it true that the event record file will be newly created (i.e. blank file) after restarting the device? So what I assume that you propose is just dumping the event record file before restarting the phone. Can I use afterwards getevent on the dumped file?

Comment: The input event file is not a regular file (like all other files under `/dev`). You can not just copy it *before restarting the phone* - you need to be reading it at the time of the input event occurring in order to capture it (the same as when using `getevent` by the way).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is directly dumping /dev/input/event7 faster than also applying getevent? If I directly dump /dev/input/event7, how can I afterwards transform the records into a format as I would get when applying getevent?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly **No**, you are doing it right.